# Create a path animation from one place to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently creating a spelling game which is currently **drag and drop**. The aim of the game is to drag the letters onto the corresponding words in the grid. The word in the grid that is next to spell is highlighted to show the user where to place the letters.

The problem is I now want to change it so you **click on the letters** and they **animate** themselves to the **specified location**

I know I have to use the JQuery **path animation** to do this but do I need to use co-ordinates or can I do it so it links to the highlighted area in the grid?

Here is the part of the **script** that deals with the **drag and drop** and the **styles** that show **correct words, incorrect words and word to be spelt.**

```
$('#pickNext').click(function() {
// remove the class from all td's
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
// pick a random word
rndWord = shuffledWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.8 - Math.random();
})[0];
// apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
$('td[data-word="' + rndWord + '"]').addClass('spellword');
});



$('.drag').draggable({

helper: 'clone',
snap: '.drop',
grid: [60, 60],
revert: function(droppable) {
    if (droppable === false) {
        return true;
    }

    else {

        return false;
    }
}
});


$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
    console.log($(event));
    console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

        $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('wordglow');
    }
    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass('wordglow2');

        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
            guesses[word].splice(0, guesses[word].length);
        }
    }






},

activate: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    // try to remove the class
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3');
}


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MgT3/1) help you.
Just add a css transition for move animation, then use jquery to set the position when a right letter is clicked...

Comment: Yes. You'll need just to move the spell validation from the drop event to square click, then get the position of the matching letter and let the css transition animate it for you. @m0onio

Comment: I have changed the spell validation but it still doesnt work @cvsguimaraes

Comment: It's a huge change in your code structure, sometimes it's better to start from zero. Good luck! @m0onio